# How to share a specific file without host mounting with Docker?

Tags: unix, docker, dockerfile

I have a container from which I want to expose files to another container without using host mounting.

In my Dockerfile I declared the `/etc/nginx/` directory as a volume after I copied the necessary files:

```
COPY ./src/frontend/config/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY ./src/frontend/config/sites-available/default /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
VOLUME ["/etc/nginx/"]
```

But because the whole directory acts as a volume the original contents of `/etc/nginx/` is shadowed by the contents of my volume:

```
dk run --volumes-from other_container -it --rm nginx:1.12.1 /bin/bash
> ls /etc/nginx
> nginx.conf sites-enabled
```

This is something which I'd like to avoid. However it seems that Docker doesn't really support exposing an existing file as a volume.

```
VOLUME ["/etc/nginx/nginx.conf"]
```

If I use the volume as above I get the following error message:

```
cannot mount volume over existing file, file exists /var/lib/docker/overlay2/b557a0d1ef5026f581f7ee69321de854d8f77b935c0442458f26cada855e5bf2/merged/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

Is it possible to solve this problem without using host mounting?

Comment: Mount somewhere else, symlink into place?

Comment: You can symlink it to another folder and then volume mount the folder to a name container. To the other container you will provide this named container

Answer (score 1):

When Docker volumes are mounted, they hide any previous content on the mountpoint.

For this reason, the volume has to be mounted in a separate directory, for instance /etc/nginx/extra/ or anywhere else. All other config files need to be adapted in order to make the includes from the right directory.